# Specific WooCommerce attribute values as list items

Tags: woocommerce, attributes

I like to list a specific WooCommerce attribute values as list items like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Attribute value 1<li>
<li>Attribute value 2<li>
</ul>
```

I have this code:

```
global $product;

if ( $product ) {
    $attributes = array( 'gyogynovenyek' );
    $output     = array();

    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_' . $attribute;
        $values   = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);

        if ( ! empty($values) ) {
            $output = '<li>' . $values . '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

the problem, it lists the values like this:

```
<li>Attribute value 1, Attribute value 2</li>
```

How should I modify the code to list values separately? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I find the answer:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'pa_gyogynovenyek' );
 
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```